# Passing a 2D array to function in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array (a chess board, but this is irrelevant to the problem) and I want to fill it using a function. The one I've written works fine, but after launching the program the console crashes. Any idea where the problem is? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void fill(int board[8][8]);
int main()
{   int board[8][8];
    fill(board);
    return 0;
}
void fill(int board[8][8])
{
    int a,b;

    for (a = 1; a <= 8; a++)
    {
        for (b = 1; b<= 8; b++)
        {
            if ((a==1) || (a==8)) board[a][b] = 7;
            if ((a==2) || (a==7)) board[a][b] = 9;
            if ((a==3) || (a==6)) board[a][b] = 11;
            if ((a==4) || (a==5)) board[a][b] = 13;
            printf("%d", board[a][b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays are zero-indexed in C; you need `for (a = 0; a < 8; a++)...`.

Comment: Of course. Thank you.

Comment: Good formatting == happy reviewer.

Answer (score 2):

I see one problem: arrays are indexed from 0 in C. So the last case is `board[7][7]`.

Accessing `board[8][0]` actually accesses the sub-array (the row) after the end of the actual array. It will compile but crash if the memory after the array isn't owned by your program (the famous segmentation fault).

I guess you should put `a-1` and `b-1` between the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

In your for-loop conditions:

> ```
> for (b = 1; b<= 8; b++)
> ```

and

> ```
> for (a = 1; a <= 8; a++)
> ```

Your for-loop runs till counter `a` and `b` is **equal** to 8. However, your array itself is deeclared as `board[[8][8]` which means that the counters for both the arrays should be from 0 to 7. Since your counter exceeds the last value of the array, it causes *undefined* behaviour, and leads to a segmentation fault.

You need to change your for-loop condition to:

```
for (b = 0; b < 8; b++)
```

and

```
for (a = 0; a < 8; a++)
```

---

EDIT: Judging from the rest of your code in the for-loop, changing the conditional statement of these loops will change the logic of your program. In that case, you could instead use `board[a -1][b - 1]` at all instances instead of `board[a][b]`.

Using this method, the counter will only reach `8 - 1 = 7` for both counter cases, and will avoid a segmentation fault just like the first solution.

Comment: Note that this will also change the logic inside the loops.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @DavidBowling, I added an alternate solution.

Comment: Just as a final note, I would probably favor the first approach, and change the logic inside the loops, since it seems unnatural to loop over an array starting from 1 in C ;).... Also, curious that this got a DV, while other less complete answers did not....

Comment: @DavidBowling That's what I also thought, let OP decide which works for him :).

Answer (score 1):

Because you have access array out of bound. Array index start to zero in c.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in several comments/answers, array index values range from 0 to n-1,

Change the following lines:

```
   for (a = 1; a <= 8; a++)
    {
        for (b = 1; b<= 8; b++)
```

To:

```
  for (a = 0; a <= 7; a++)
    {
        for (b = 0; b<= 7; b++)
```

Follow this with adjustments to the comparison statements in the inner loop accordingly.

Comment: Just as a note, this will affect the logic of the program: `if ((a==1) || (a==8))`

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer - Yes, I was still editing, thank you.