# How to fix output in matrix transposing problem in C?

Tags: c

I trying to transpose a 4x5 matrix using user entered values to a 5x4 matrix.
The last row of the matrix seems to not be transposing correctly.

I have tried switching the parameters of my for loop but I'm sure I am doing it right.

```
int MATRANS(int original[4][5], int transpose[5][4])
{
    int ROW, COL;

    for (ROW = 1; ROW <=4; ROW++)                                  
    {
        for (COL = 1; COL <= 5; COL++)
        {
            transpose[COL][ROW]= original[ROW][COL];
        }
    }
}
```

```
//Printing Matrix Z//
printf("Transposed Matrix:\n");
for (row=1; row< 6; row++)
{  
    for (col=1; col < 5; col++)
    {
        printf("%d ", matrixZ[row][col]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

```
The output when you enter all 1's is 

1111
1111
1111
1111
1251

when I expect it to be 

1111
1111
1111
1111
1111
```

Comment: Array indices in C start at *zero* ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a 2D array to function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018001/passing-a-2d-array-to-function-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

While printing matrixZ you have given 
'for (I= 1; I< 6; I++)' which means the loop will iterate 5 times.

and in the matrans it is  i< =4  which means it will iterate 4 times.
Same for another for loop at one place you have given.
col <= 5 and at the other col< 5

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your for loop begins from 1 instead of 0.

```
int MATRANS(int original[4][5], int transpose[5][4]) {
    int ROW, COL; 
    for (ROW = 0; ROW <4; ROW++) { 
        for (COL = 0; COL < 5; COL++){ 
            transpose[COL][ROW]= original[ROW][COL]; 
        } 
    } 
}
```